# Python dictonary with string placeholders and defaults

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following problem in python2.7. I want to have a template dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {
    'key_1' : %(key_1)s,
    'key_2' : %(key_2)s,
}
```

and I want to use it like this:

```
new_dict = my_dict % {'key_1': 'something', 'key_2': 'anything'}
```

but this is raising an exception:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'dict' and 'dict'`

My question has two points here:

1. Is there any way or structure, preferably dictionary, to achieve this:
2. Considering there is, is there a way to default the values if no value is passed ?

What I mean with 2 is:

```
my_dict = {
    'key_1' : %s or None, # if no value is interpolated at key 'key_1'
}
```

Comment: I'm very confused by your question.  This is not valid python code: `my_dict = {'key_1' : %(key_1)s, 'key_2' : %(key_2)s,}`.  Nor is this: `my_dict % {'key_1': 'something', 'key_2': 'anything'}`.  Could you explain in more what you want to accomplish (and possibly why)?

Comment: `blah-blah % values` is deprecated, try using `str.format(..)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template = {
    'key_1' : '%(key_1)s',
    'key_2' : '%(key_2)s',
}

values_dict = {'key_1': 'something', 'key_2': 'anything'}
```

Then to make a new `dict` with all the formatting:

```
new_dict = dict((key, template[key] % values_dict) for key, value in template.items())
```

Or if you're ok updating the original `dict`:

```
for key, value in template.items():
    template[key] %= values_dict
```